# 2 and 3 key not working any more in 4.0.2 in edit mode

Tags: shortcut

- Blender 4.0.2
- Keyboard typematrix
- Layout bépo

<kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd> key doesn’t work any more in *Edit Mode*
and no more special character is allowed (f. ex. by renaming objects)

in *Preferences > Key Bindings*, <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd> key aren’t recognized any more.

Do you know what the problem is?